# update factory value when controller data changed

Tags: angularjs, factory

i have a factory in my app:

```
dashboard.factory('ProxyStatusFactory', ['$resource','CodisData', function ($resource,CodisData) {
    return $resource('http://' + CodisData.Addr + '/api/proxy', {}, {
            query:{ method: 'GET', url : 'http://' + CodisData.Addr + '/api/proxy/list', isArray: true },
              setStatus:{ method: 'POST' }
          });
}]);
```

the `CodisData` is a angular value

```
dashboard.value("CodisData",{"Name":"NA","Addr":"NA"});
```

then i use it in my controller like this:

```
    $scope.codis_name = selected.Tag;
    $scope.codis_addr = selected.Addr;
    CodisData.Addr = selected.Addr;
    $scope.proxy_array = ProxyStatusFactory.query();
```

i changed CodisData.Addr ,but in ProxyStatusFactory ,$resource also return 'http://na/api/proxy'

so when CodisData change,how synchronized update ProxyStatusFactory and return  correct $resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
dashboard.factory('ProxyStatusFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://:addr/api/proxy/', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET', 
            url: 'http://:addr/api/proxy/list',
            params: {},
            isArray: true
        },
        setStatus:{ method: 'POST' }
    });
}]);
```

then use in controller like this:

```
ProxyStatusFactory.query({addr: CodisData.Addr});
```

Moving forward with explanation...
angular factory/service are singletons, so they are created only ONCE. So http url is also created only once, based on current value of `CodisData.Addr`. 
Thats why `+ CodisData.Addr +` is changed to `:addr` to make this part of url configurable....

I hope this helps :)

@update

tested on local project and injecting variables into url part, works as expected, but when desired url is external rest api then it fails with message you describe.

In that case You can dynamically create $resource object. Here is jsfiddle with working factory that creates resources dynamically.
https://jsfiddle.net/qwetty/mxrz2cxh/13/

Comment: thanks for your help,but i fellow your order,it seems not work `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://:addr/api/proxy/list. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.` but i change it like this `query:{ method: 'GET', url:':addr/api/proxy/list', isArray: true },` it worked `LHttpRequest cannot load %310.0.0.1:6000/api/proxy/list. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`,how to add`http://`?

Comment: Are you sure You call your factory with proper arguments: `ProxyStatusFactory.query({addr: CodisData.Addr});`?  It is important to have `{addr: CodisData.Addr}` inside `query` method.